# AD FS installation pre-requisite check fails - the target computer is not joined to a domain

Tags: installation, domain, windows-server-2012-r2

I am currently trying to install to install AD FS 3.0 on a **domain controller** running **Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Edition** (English language). Hereby installer and post-installation configuration wizard are both running on the domain controller to install AD FS on itself.

However the **post-installation** configuration wizard fails at the 'Pre-requisite checks' step with the following error message (twice):

```
(x) The target computer is not joined to a domain. 
    Only machines that are joined to a domain can be members of a AD FS farm.
(x) The target computer is not joined to a domain. 
    Only machines that are joined to a domain can be members of a AD FS farm.
(i) Prerequisites Check completed
(x) One or more prerequisites failed. Please fix these issues and click "Rerun 
    prerequisite check"
```

Checking via Computer > Properties (System) or using the Server Manager both show that the computer is in a domain.

The installation user is both Domain Administrator as well as Enterprise Administrator.

-----------------------------------------------------
The following has been attempted thus far, partially inspired by different Technet posts:

**1.)** Rebooting twice and subsequently running the configuration wizard -> issue persists

**2.)** Verifying the domain server with

```
echo %LOGONSERVER%
```

and

```
whoami
```

which show the correct domain and the domain controller as log-on server. Under computer properties > Full computer name it lists the Domain as part of the FQDN

**3.)** Checking event viewer for warning/errors -> no related events found

**4.)** Running the post-installation configuration wizard as another user with Domain Administrator permissions -> same error

**5.)** Running the post-installation configuration wizard as Local Administrator -> same error

**6.)** Running the post-installation configuration wizard in PowerShell which results in the same error message

```
Install-AdfsFarm : The target computer is not joined to a domain. Only machines that are 
joined to a domain can be members of a AD FS farm.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-AdfsFarm `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-AdfsFarm],
                              PrerequsiteFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PreCheckTest,
                        Microsoft.IdentityServer.Deployment.Commands.InstallFarmCommand
```

-----------------------------------------------------
How do I solve this issue to install AD FS?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC I had this problem myself a couple months ago and after much searching found my solution after realizing the Microsoft Key Distribution Service was not starting: [ADFS 3.0 service hangs at startup on a domain controller](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mapo/2015/07/07/adfs-3-0-service-hangs-at-startup-on-a-domain-controller/).  The article recommends running the following command (an Administrator Command Prompt will do nicely):

```
sc triggerinfo kdssvc start/networkon
```